# How do I keep view template from loading until all Promise data has resolved? [Angular2, JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, angular, es6-promise

I'm trying to get my app to render data that is the result of async http requests which return Promises. I've set up my code so that its executed in the `ngOnInit` method, so that all the logic will process before the view renders. However, I'm having an issue where most of the Promise data loads before its rendered, but some of the data lags (probably due to multiple HTTP requests), so the rest of the view is already rendered and then that data pops in several seconds later.

[Here is the full codebase on Github](https://github.com/mattlayton1986/pokedex-onsen).

I'm fairly new to Angular2 and ES6 Promises, so I'm still playing around with how Promises resolve and send back data so bear with me.

My `loadMore()` method is called from `ngOnInit` to load initial data when the page is loaded.

```
loadMore() {
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.pokedexService.getPokemon(this.pokemon.length, 9)
    .then(pokemon => {
      pokemon = pokemon.map(p => {
        p.imageLoaded = false;
        this.pokedexService.getPokemonTypes(p.id)
        .then(types => {
          p.types = types;
        });
        return p;
      });

      this.pokemon = this.pokemon.concat(pokemon);
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.error = false;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.error = true;
      this.isLoading = false;
    })
  }
```

Part of the issue (I think) is the number of calls to the API: `getPokemon()` makes one call to retrieve 9 Pokemon API resources, and then `getPokemonTypes()` makes one call for each of those 9 API resources. Both methods return Promises -- however, the data loaded from `getPokemon()` loads into the view properly; its the Pokemon types that are loaded from each call to `getPokemonTypes()` that pops into the view after the fact. Here is the logic from `pokedex.service.ts` for both `get` methods:

```
getPokemon(offset: number, limit: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().results)
    .then(items => items.map((item, idx) => {
      const id: number = idx + offset + 1;
      return {
        name: item.name,
        sprite: `${this.baseSpriteUrl}${id}.png`,
        id
      };
    }));
  }

  getPokemonTypes(id: number): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}${id}/`)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(details => {
      const types = details.types
      .map(t => {
        return t.type.name;
      });
      return types;
    });
```

What would be the best way to optimize the code to make ALL the data load together without creating a several (5-7) second delay in rendering the data?

Comment: observables! angular is built around them - they are much more flexible than promises - check out RxJS

Comment: I'm still new to es6 features and angular2 -- I've read a bit about observables but don't currently know how to use them well enough to implement it in this scenario (otherwise this.http.get would return an Observable, but i've used .toPromise() to keep things in the Promise paradigm for now, since its what I'm more comfortable with).

Comment: You can read this article to understand how to convert promise chain to observable chain: https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/q-map-to-rxjs-981936a2b22d

Comment: observables are very very powerful, and well worth getting your head around... at the moment you have got promises flying all over the place, split between your service and component which needn't be the case (and does not separate concerns very well). RxJS has many methods for combining streams of data like you have here and would be a good fit from what I can see here of your situation

Comment: While observables would make your resolution more flexible it doesn't manage the fact that your API makes 1 and then 9 more calls,  I would look for a way to make less calls.  Do you also control the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments above Observerables are very powerful and you can use plenty of operators to make stuff work more efficient. If you still want to use toPromise the i guess you can let your service handle getPokemonType in getPokemon method. You call getPokemon and once that is resolved you simply map it to getPokemonType in service. Then you have only one promise to resolve in your component.